# Titanium encodeURIComponent returns different value iOS / Android

Tags: javascript, titanium

This simple script returns deferrent values for iOS/Android.

My environment is titanium 6.0.1.GA

```
var name = "arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1";

Ti.API.info("encodeTest:" + encodeURIComponent(name);
```

[iOS]

encodeTest:arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aap-northeast-1

[android]

encodeTest:arn%%3Aaws%%3Asns%%3Aap-northeast-1

somehow in android escape character '%' is doubled.

I have used this encodeURIComponent function many times before, but at that time (may be titanium 5.0.*.GA), it didn't happnen.

Comment: that sounds like a bug in 6.0.1. If it still happens in 6.0.2 and/or 6.0.3 please report it at JIRA: https://jira.appcelerator.org

Comment: I have tested 6.0.2 and 6.0.3 . same things happen.

Comment: I made new articles here , then plannning to report to appcelerator jira http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251742/a-letter-is-doubled-on-android

Comment: don't create new questions on Stackoverflow if the question is the same...