# A letter '%' is doubled on Android

Tags: titanium

Environment Titanium 6.0.3.GA / 6.0.2.GA / 6.0.1.GA

```
var myname = "%";
Ti.API.info("test:" + myname);
```

This simple code shows different output

Android

```
[INFO]  test:%%
```

iOS

```
[INFO]  test:%
```

THis is the further investigation of [Titanium encodeURIComponent returns different value iOS / Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201488/titanium-encodeuricomponent-returns-different-value-ios-android)

It might be bug or not ??

---

I tried these too

```
var myname = "1%1";
var myname = '1%1';
var myname = "1\%1";
```

Everything shows (on Android)

```
[INFO]  test:1%%1
```

Comment: Someone left a comment on that post you have mentioned, have you tried that?

Comment: If it sounds like a bug and looks like a bug, it may be a bug! Does this just happen for the % character or is it happening for you with other characters / words? Either way, I think reporting it to appcelerator is the way to go.

Comment: @ C0dekid @ Liam MacDonald , OK I will report to them.

Comment: @Liam MacDonald, for now it happens only for '%' ,for other characters like :/-~  doesn't happen.

Comment: put it in their jira bugtracker if you got a good testcase. What happens if you print something like this on screen? Also what if you use `console.log()`

Comment: I have no privilege to post on Jira (I asked to the administrator though, no reply), could anyone post for me?? It is very basic problem.